# how to close windows 11 ad windows

Tags: windows-11

The `win+w` shortcut of windows11 has now been changed to an advertisement page. I would like to know how to permanently close it (even if it is just to close its update)

I tried the approach mentioned [here](https://bynss.com/howto/922024.html), creating a new `AllowNewsAndInterests` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft` and setting it to `0`, but it resets when I restart the computer.

Comment: If you want to *block* ads and other intrusion on privacy, try a third-party tool such as O&O ShutUp10, https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10 .  You can select which items to allow or to block in fine granularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more place in the registry that needs to be set.
You may use the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\NewsAndInterests\AllowNewsAndInterests]
"value"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Dsh]
"AllowNewsAndInterests"=dword:00000000
```

It might be simpler to use the Local Group Policy Editor as follows,
if you have Windows 11 Pro, Enterprise, or Education:

- Open the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to the policy
  `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Widgets​`
- On the right, double-click on "Allow widgets policy" to edit it
- Select Disabled, then OK.

Comment: I saved and executed the .reg file you mentioned, and after restarting the computer I found that the win+w shortcut no longer works, is this consistent with what you think is the correct result?

Comment: According to the documentation that's not supposed to happen - it may be out of date. Does the Group Policy help?

Comment: my windows is home single language version, no group policy

Comment: I don't use the window that pops up after pressing the win+w shortcut, so your solution solved my problem, thanks.