# How to disable some windows11 shortcut keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

How to turn off the following shortcuts
`win + h`
`win + c`
`win + k`
They are really annoying when I accidentally press the wrong one

I'm not trying to modify these shortcut keys to third-party software, [like this](https://superuser.com/a/1147521/1201789)
, I just want to ban them completely, and only ban these three.

According to the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/a/1147521/1201789), modifying the registry seems to have no effect, and my attempts in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1742739/how-to-close-windows-11-ad-windows) also tell me that the modified registry will be invalid after restarting the computer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will nullify the keys system-wide:

```
#h::
#c::
#k::
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

You may further limit the script to a specific executable by
adding an
[#IfWinActive directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm)
to the script.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: In AutoHotkey 2.0, you need to add a function body: `#h::{
 return
}`

Answer (score -1):

the "System Preferences" option. From the list on the left side of your screen, choose "Keyboard." In the list of settings at the top of the window, select "Shortcuts." To disable a shortcut, uncheck the box next to it in the "Shortcuts" section.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots, I'm a Chinese user and I can't find where those buttons you said are located

Comment: I'm pretty sure these instructions are for MacOS not Windows 11 :/

Comment: Well, my problem is in windows11 environment